# How to use Activity code in SherlockFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, actionbarsherlock

I have written some activities in which i am fetching data into ListView using JSON, but now i have to use Navigation Drawer in my app using Sherlock Fragment, and I have made Fragments to use and simply showing text message in each and every Fragment.

**Fragment1.java:**

```
public class Fragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**fragment1.xml:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/Fragment1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But now i need to use my existing code in which i used Activity, in SherlockFragment, So here i want to know what are the changes i need to do in my code ?

For an example how to use this tutorial code in SherlockFragment:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-multilevel-listview-tutorial/

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html. check the docs the lifecycle methods of fragments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. inflate layout in `onCreateView()`
2. get references of all views using `findViewById()` in `onActivityCreated()`
3. start JSON Parsing in `onCreate()` or wherever you want
4. populate `ListView` after fetching data from JSON.

Comment: in short i want to know, working with Fragment is different from working with Activity or not? If (Yes) so what percent in your idea?

Comment: AFAIK..Fragments are light weight and reusable. They have their own lifecycle methods(onCreate(), onResume() etc..) same as Activity.

Comment: also fragments are hosted by a activity

Comment: as i asked like i have written classes in activity now i need to use those code in Fragments so i need to do big changes in my code or just few changes will work for me @Raghunandan

Comment: @Ketan i hope you will not mind, can you please show me the code by which i can understand the way how to use ListView in Fragments

Comment: sure..please have a look at [here](http://www.easyinfogeek.com/2013/07/full-example-of-using-fragment-in.html)